# Play reactivemongo doesnt stop

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, swagger, reactivemongo

In my play/swagger/reactivemongo application i use the following function in the controller to get a list of results with "EntityID" 8.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Gets the item of a specific ID", notes = "Returns an Item", responseClass = "Item", httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiErrors(Array(
new ApiError(code = 400, reason = "Invalid ID supplied"),
new ApiError(code = 404, reason = "Item not found")))
def index = Action { implicit request =>
 Async {
  // test id
  var myVar: Int = 8

  val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collection.find(Json.obj("EntityID" -> myVar))
  .sort(Json.obj("_id" -> -1))
  .cursor[JsObject]
  // gather all the JsObjects in a list
  val futureUsersList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.toList

  // transform the list into a JsArray
  val futureUsersListJs: Future[JsArray] = futureUsersList.map { Measurements_live =>
    Json.arr(Measurements_live)
  }

  futureUsersListJs.map { Measurements_live =>
    Ok(Measurements_live)
  }
 }
}
```

The measurements model:

```
case class Measurements_live(
EntityID: Int,
SensorID: Int,
Datetime: Date,
Value: String)

object JsonFormats {
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

implicit val measureFormat = Json.format[Measurements_live]
val measureForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "EntityID" -> number,
    "SensorID" -> number,
    "Datetime" ->  date,
    "Value" -> text)(Measurements_live.apply _)(Measurements_live.unapply _))
}
```

The problems is that it wont stop loading. There are a total of 35000 objects in the database. 
I've played with cursor.close() that stops the cursor and that will return some results. What i want is that the cursor automatically closes when all results are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct is "that's a **lot** of objects to be fetching in one HTTP request!".

I can't say exactly why this doesn't work but I suspect it's the collating into a `Future[List[JsObject]]` that is killing the thing.

I would use the version of `Cursor.toList()` that [takes an `upTo` parameter](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.9/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.Cursor), set that to a reasonable number (say 100) and then allow the client to specify which `page` of results they want to see as a parameter. You could even let the client set the page size if you trust them not to get too greedy.

Obviously you'll need to add another clause to your `find` to get the correct offset for the pagination; if your client just tells you the highest `_id` value that they've already got, your `find()` query would still be very simple.